# Symfony using salt in encodePassword

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.6

I am using Symfony 2.6.6 and I am currently trying to use a salt on my database users. In the registration process I do the following hash while persist the user information via Doctrine.

<kbd>src/AppBundle/Form/RegisterFormType.php</kbd>

```
<?php

$account->setSalt(base_convert(sha1(uniqid(mt_rand(), true)), 16, 36));
$account->setPassword($this->encodePassword($account, $account->getPlainPassword()));
```

In that same file I have this function:

```
<?php

private function encodePassword(Account $account, $plainPassword)
{
    $encoder = $this->container->get('security.encoder_factory')->getEncoder($account);

    return $encoder->encodePassword($plainPassword, $account->getSalt());
}
```

This is my security.yml file:

<kbd>app/config/security.yml</kbd>

```
security:
    encoders:
        AppBundle\Entity\Account: bcrypt

    providers:
        database_users:
            entity: { class: AppBundle:Account }

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt|error)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        prod:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                check_path: account_login_check
                login_path: account_login
                csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
            logout:
                path: account_logout
                target: home
            anonymous: ~
            switch_user: ~
            remember_me:
                key: "%secret%"

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/account/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/account/register, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/account/logout, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

In my Entity, these are the salt keys:

<kbd>src/AppBundle/Entity/Account.php</kbd>

```
<?php // src/AppBundle/Entity/Account.php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Role\Role;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\AdvancedUserInterface;
use Serializable;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="accounts")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Entity\AccountRepository")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields="username", message="That username is taken!")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields="email", message="That email is taken!")
 */
class Account implements AdvancedUserInterface, Serializable
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="username", type="string", length=30)
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Give us at least 3 characters")
     * @Assert\Length(min=3, minMessage="Give us at least 3 characters!")
     */
    private $username;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="password", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="salt", type="string")
     */
    private $salt;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=120)
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     * @Assert\Email
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="json_array")
     */
    private $roles = array();

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
     */
    private $isActive = false;

    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     * @Assert\Regex(
     *      pattern="/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?!.*\s).*$/",
     *      message="Use 1 upper case letter, 1 lower case letter, and 1 number"
     * )
     */
    private $plainPassword;

    /**
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $username
     * @return Account
     */
    public function setUsername($username)
    {
        $this->username = $username;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $email
     * @return Account
     */
    public function setEmail($email)
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $password
     * @return Account
     */
    public function setPassword($password)
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPlainPassword()
    {
        return $this->plainPassword;
    }

    /**
     * @param $plainPassword
     * @return string
     */
    public function setPlainPassword($plainPassword)
    {
        $this->plainPassword = $plainPassword;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return array Role
     */
    public function getRoles()
    {
        $roles = $this->roles;
        $roles[] = 'ROLE_USER';

        return array_unique($roles);
    }

    /**
     * @param array $roles
     * @return Role
     */
    public function setRoles(array $roles)
    {
        $this->roles = $roles;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Removes sensitive data from the user
     */
    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
        $this->setPlainPassword(null);
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getSalt()
    {
        return $this->salt;
    }

    /**
     * @param $salt
     * @return Account
     */
    public function setSalt($salt)
    {
        $this->salt = $salt;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function getIsActive()
    {
        return $this->isActive;
    }

    /**
     * @param boolean $isActive
     */
    public function setIsActive($isActive)
    {
        $this->isActive = $isActive;
    }

    public function isAccountNonExpired()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function isAccountNonLocked()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function isCredentialsNonExpired()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function isEnabled()
    {
        return $this->getIsActive();
    }

    public function serialize()
    {
        return serialize(array(
            $this->id,
            $this->username,
            $this->password,
            $this->salt
        ));
    }

    public function unserialize($serialized)
    {
        list (
            $this->id,
            $this->username,
            $this->password,
            $this->salt
        ) = unserialize($serialized);
    }
}
```

When I login, it works, but the Profiler tells me that `Authenticated?` says no. When I change the salt to something different in the database, the user can still login.

Is there something I am missing from the Symfony documentation or do I need to change the whole way of salting?

EDIT: I am sorry I did not include that I serialize and unserialize `$this->password, $this->salt`.

EDIT 2: Included `app/config/security.yml` and posted full `src/AppBundle/Entity/Account.php` file by user:[ghanbari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29660848/symfony-using-salt-in-encodepassword#comment47476770_29660848)'s request.

Thank you for reading my question.

Comment: can place encoders & providers part of your security.yml here?

Comment: and plz place Your account entity class here too, thanks

Comment: in symfony 2.6, you can use "security.password_encoder" service, that is easier

Comment: @ghanbari: I have included them in my orginal post.

Comment: you must add properties that use in AdvancedUserInterface Methods to serialize & unserialize

Comment: oops, bcript no need to a salt, because that have a built in generator, then you must return a empty string from getSalt() method, read note from this article http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/entity_provider.html#creating-your-first-user

Comment: @ghanbari I see, I overlooked that part of the cookbook. I'll accept your answer with the edited Entity as that solves the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, your `User` object must implement `Serializable` interface, and you must serialize id & salt.

Read [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/entity_provider.html#cookbook-security-serialize-equatable).

---

EDIT: your entity class must be like this:

```
<?php // src/AppBundle/Entity/Account.php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Role\Role;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\AdvancedUserInterface;
use Serializable;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="accounts")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Entity\AccountRepository")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields="username", message="That username is taken!")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields="email", message="That email is taken!")
 */
class Account implements AdvancedUserInterface, Serializable
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="username", type="string", length=30)
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Give us at least 3 characters")
     * @Assert\Length(min=3, minMessage="Give us at least 3 characters!")
     */
    private $username;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="password", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="salt", type="string")
     */
    private $salt;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=120)
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     * @Assert\Email
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="json_array")
     */
    private $roles = array();

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
     */
    private $isActive = false;

    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     * @Assert\Regex(
     *      pattern="/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?!.*\s).*$/",
     *      message="Use 1 upper case letter, 1 lower case letter, and 1 number"
     * )
     */
    private $plainPassword;

    /**
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $username
     * @return Account
     */
    public function setUsername($username)
    {
        $this->username = $username;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $email
     * @return Account
     */
    public function setEmail($email)
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $password
     * @return Account
     */
    public function setPassword($password)
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPlainPassword()
    {
        return $this->plainPassword;
    }

    /**
     * @param $plainPassword
     * @return string
     */
    public function setPlainPassword($plainPassword)
    {
        $this->plainPassword = $plainPassword;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return array Role
     */
    public function getRoles()
    {
        $roles = $this->roles;
        $roles[] = 'ROLE_USER';

        return array_unique($roles);
    }

    /**
     * @param array $roles
     * @return Role
     */
    public function setRoles(array $roles)
    {
        $this->roles = $roles;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Removes sensitive data from the user
     */
    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
        $this->setPlainPassword(null);
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getSalt()
    {
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * @param $salt
     * @return Account
     */
    public function setSalt($salt)
    {
        $this->salt = $salt;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function getIsActive()
    {
        return $this->isActive;
    }

    /**
     * @param boolean $isActive
     */
    public function setIsActive($isActive)
    {
        $this->isActive = $isActive;
    }

    public function isAccountNonExpired()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function isAccountNonLocked()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function isCredentialsNonExpired()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function isEnabled()
    {
        return $this->getIsActive();
    }

    public function serialize()
    {
        return serialize(array(
            $this->id,
            $this->username,
            $this->password,
            $this->salt,
            $this->isActive
        ));
    }

    public function unserialize($serialized)
    {
        list (
            $this->id,
            $this->username,
            $this->password,
            $this->salt,
            $this->isActive
            ) = unserialize($serialized);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I followed that cookbook item to create my account system, I forgot to add this information to my question. I do serialize the password and salt.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Serializble interface and implments its methods called serializable and unserializable. Define your salt varible inside both the function.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I forgot to add this information to my question, I do serialize the password and salt.